# can counting sort algorithm be simplified

Tags: algorithm, sorting

To better express my idea, we set:

- A[] - the original array of numbers that need to be sorted;
- B[] - the auxiliary array, and the max index of B[] is the largest
  value in A[];
- C[] - the result array that has the same length as A[];

For example, we have A[5] with values of {3, 2, 4, 1, 2}.

1. First we will count the frequency of each value in B[5], and we get
   {0, 1, 2, 1, 1}.
2. Then we need to calculate the amount of number that is less than or equal to A[i] by adding B[i] with B[i-1]. So B becomes {0, 1, 3, 4, 5} now.
3. We go to A[i] and check the value in B[A[i]] to check how many number is less than or equal to A[i], then C[B[A[i]] - 1] = A[i], B[A[i]] = B[A[i]]-- (i from MAX to 0)

My question is WHY WE NEED STEP 2 AND STEP 3? Instead, why we don't check the frequency in STEP 1 and insert the index value of B into C for B[i] times to directly get the sorted array C?

Comment: When you say "directly insert", by "directly", do you mean we should skip one of the above steps, or do you mean that inserting numbers into C should be the next thing we do?

Comment: After creating the frequency in array B, then the next step would directly store numbers into array C to get the sorted array. So something that you've read or heard about in class is suggesting yet another step between creating the frequency array B and storing numbers into array C? During the process the index into array C is being incremented, and on frequency boundaries, it ends up representing the amount of numbers less than A[i], is that the question?

Comment: @user2357112  I mean the following steps I saw on the book is to convert B into {0, 1, 3, 4, 5} by adding each element with the previous element, and then C[B[A[i]]] = A[i]. My question is why we do not just insert i of B in to C for B[i] times into C when B is still {0, 1, 2, 1, 1}, it looks much simpler.

Comment: @Jiang: Yeah, that works. Your book is complicating things unnecessarily.

Comment: @rcgldr Sorry for the confusion. I've edited the question to better express my idea. I want to change step 2 and step 3 into just one step

Comment: @Jiang - The method in the book is similar to what is used for counting / radix sort, but as commented already, it's not needed for a simple counting sort. Perhaps the next lesson in the book will be counting / radix sort which is why they made counting sort more complicated than it needs to be.